# Cross browser support jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, compatibility

jQuery is famous for cross browser compatibility but, which all properties or functions don't have a cross browser support?

I know one: `ui-corner-all` class won't produce rounded corner effect in any IE browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a [jQuery Core](http://jquery.com/) feature, but a [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) one.  When it comes to jQuery UI the *functionality* will work, but older browsers may not get all the bells and whistles with the styling.